# How to automatically set the Application Pool Identity, User Name & Password

Tags: application-pool, windows-scripting, command-line-tool, appcmd, applicationpoolidentity

## Question

How can I automatically set the password of the Application Pool Identity from within a Windows commandline interface or script?

## What I have Tried

I have tried to following command in command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='MyAppPool'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='MyAppPool'].processModel.userName:MY_USER /[name='MyAppPool'].processModel.password:MY_PASSWORD
```

I get the error message:

> ```
> Failed to process input: Duplicate parameters passed: section
> (HRESULT=800700b7).
> ```

I have narrowed it down to being a problem with the password, as the following command does work:

```
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='MyAppPool'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='MyAppPool'].processModel.userName:MY_USER
```

I also tried running the password command on its own:

```
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='MyAppPool'].processModel.password:MY_PASSWORD
```

But it gives this error instead:

> ```
> ERROR ( message:Malformed collection indexer; format is [@position,name='value',name2='value2',...].  The @position specifier is optional, and be '@start', '@end', or '@N' where N is a numeric index into the collection. )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for how to do it, and I found this topic. I tried to do it as you say but finally I managed it with the other format:

```
set apppool "AppPoolName" /processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /processModel.userName:MY_USER /processModel.password:MY_PASSWORD
```